# How do you configure Create React App to use CSS Blocks?

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, jsx, create-react-app

CSS blocks just went open source and I wanted to incorporate it into my React app while still using the boilerplate CRA webpack because I want to keep all the other functionality.

From what I understand the majority of the configuration is simply adding another babel-loader with the css-block plugin.

So instead of just:

```
{
            test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
            include: paths.appSrc,
            loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
            options: {

              // This is a feature of `babel-loader` for webpack (not Babel itself).
              // It enables caching results in ./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/
              // directory for faster rebuilds.
              cacheDirectory: true,
            },
          },
```

You follow it with:

```
{
        test: /\.[j|t]s(x?)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [

          {
            loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
            options: {
              presets: [require.resolve("babel-preset-react-app")],
              cacheDirectory: true,
              compact: true,
            }
          },

          // Run the css-blocks plugin in its own dedicated loader because the react-app preset
          // steps on our transforms' feet. This way, we are guaranteed a clean pass before any
          // other transforms are done.
          {
            loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
            options: {
              plugins: [
                require("@css-blocks/jsx/dist/src/transformer/babel").makePlugin({ rewriter: CssBlockRewriter }),
              ],
              cacheDirectory: true,
              compact: true,
              parserOpts: {
                plugins: [
                  "jsx",
                  "doExpressions",
                  "objectRestSpread",
                  "decorators",
                  "classProperties",
                ]
              }
            }
          },
```

But, I cannot for the life of me get the second bit to parse anything. It's like it doesn't even exist and my CSS modules are just being referenced inside the class. Result ends up being like:

```
<div class="/src/test.css">
```

instead of

```
<div class="a b cD">
```

If anyone has any pointers of where I should try to look I would greatly appreciate it!

P.S. For reference I'll include links to the docs below since it's very new

http://css-blocks.com/

https://github.com/linkedin/css-blocks/blob/master/packages/%40css-blocks/website/config/webpack.config.dev.js

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://github.com/linkedin/css-blocks/tree/master/packages/@css-blocks/website

Comment: that's primarily where I got my setup from unfortunately :/ for some reason the links didn't get added on my post. 

I will be sure to update this post if I do manage to get it set up though.

Comment: If you chang `test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/` to `test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs|tsx)$/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the example from Linkedin example `/website` and works fine with `react-create-app scripts`.

Fallow boilerplate extracted from [CSS Blocks](https://github.com/linkedin/css-blocks/tree/master/packages/%40css-blocks/website) by me [ralfting/boilerplate-css-blocks](https://github.com/ralfting/boilerplate-css-blocks)... Maybe this help you.

Comment: Thanks for separating that out for me. I've pulled and tried to run it and I can see that it did generate the css-blocks.css file. But, now the components are not being rendered in the root. It's possible that I'm missing something because I don't use typescript.

The console is outputting an error "styles is not defined"

Comment: @MichaelSorensen I have the same problem, this happens when style class is not defined or when set state (class state) directly in className (className={styles.isactive()}).

so I created a constant and put state inside: 

const menuStyle = objstr({
   [styles]: true,
   [style.isactive()]: <condition>
});

and after I set in my className.

Comment: I tried this as well and I just tried it again using your boilerplate and I still get 'styles is not defined'. I think my build is having trouble interpreting 'import styles from "App.block.css"' because the cli says it's just getting tossed. 

WARNING: Stray reference to block import (styles). Imports are removed during re
write so this will probably be a runtime error.

Comment: Also, I wanted to say I do appreciate your help ralfting. I think it might just be us trying to figure this out ;D

Comment: @MichaelSorensen you're welcome let's figure out this... Do you have this file [import-css.d.ts](https://gist.github.com/ralfting/59ad9606888e0f94eca00f763f5e5d6c)  in local-types?

Comment: yeppers. I'm just trying to run this using the boilerplate repo you provided. If the boilerplate works on your system then I'm probably missing something unrelated to CSS-Blocks. hrmmmm

Comment: I'm marking this question as answered because, your boilerplate is allowing me to compile the CSS into the CSS-blocks file. I think I'm just having an issue correctly configuring typescript on my machine. I'll post another question for that if I am unable to figure it out!

Comment: @MichaelSorensen thanks! Paste the new question here, for I see as well.